# Prove that the running time of quick sort after modification = O(Nk)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, quicksort

this is a homework question, and I'm not that at finding the complixity but I'm trying my best!

- Three-way partitioning is a modification of quicksort that partitions elements into groups smaller than, equal to, and larger than the pivot. Only the groups of smaller and larger elements need to be recursively sorted. Show that if there are N items but only k unique values (in other words there are many duplicates), then the running time of this modification to quicksort is O(Nk).

my try:

on the average case:

the tree subroutines will be at these indices:

I assume that the subroutine that have duplicated items will equal (n-k)

- first: from 0 - to(i-1)
- Second: i - (i+(n-k-1))
- third: (i+n-k) - (n-1)
- number of comparisons = (n-k)-1

So,

```
T(n) = (n-k)-1 + Sigma from 0 until (n-k-1) [ T(i) + T (i-k)]
```

then I'm not sure how I'm gonna continue :S

It might be a very bad start though :$
Hope to find a help

Comment: You might also try here: [Theoretical Computer Science (StackExchange)](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Quick sort is often analyzed average case only. Is that the case here too, or are you talking worst case?

Comment: @Groo, it seems like I'm on my way to find the answer here, thnx though!

Comment: @ThomasAhle nope, I'm talking average case.

Comment: @Sosy: And how do you choose the pivot? The first value in the subsequence to be sorted?

Comment: @Groo: That's for research level TCS questions. This is undergraduate level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't look at the average case since the upper bound of `O(nk)` can be proved for the worst case, which is a stronger statement.

You should look at the maximum possible depth of recursion. In normal quicksort, the maximum depth is `n`. For each level, the total number of operations done is `O(n)`, which gives `O(n^2)` total in the worst case.

Here, it's not hard to prove that the maximum possible depth is `k` (since one unique value will be removed at each level), which leads to `O(nk)` total.

Comment: great! I did try to prove the depth by taking an example: 1 1 2 2 3 4. so level_2: 2 2 3 4, level_3: 3 4 and level_5: 4. thats why we said the depth is k right? hmm do I have to find the formula? I tried to and I got T(n)=T(n-k)+n, is it right? Thanks A Lot @interjay!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a formal education in complexity. But if you think about it as a mathematical problem, you can prove it as a mathematical proof.

For all sorting algorithms, the best case scenario will always be *O(n)* for *n* elements because to sort *n* elements you have to consider each one atleast once. Now, for your particular optimisation of quicksort, what you have done is simplified the issue because now, you are only sorting unique values: All the values that are the same as the pivot are already considered sorted, and by virtue of its nature, quicksort will guarantee that every unique value will feature as the pivot at some point in the operation, so this eliminates duplicates.

This means for an *N* size list, quicksort must perform some operation *N* times (once for every position in the list), and because it is trying to sort the list, that operation is trying to find the position of that value in the list, but because you are effectively dealing with just unique values, and there are *k* of those, the quicksort algorithm must perform *k* comparisons for each element. So it performs *Nk* operations for an *N* sized list with *k* unique elements.

To summarise:

- This algorithm eliminates checking against duplicate values.
- But all sorting algorithms must look at every value in the list at least once. *N operations*
- For every value in the list the operation is to find its position relative to other values in the list.
- Because duplicates get removed, this leaves only *k* values to check against.
- *O(Nk)*

Comment: wow it's very clear when you say it like that, thanks a lot @asQuirreL  !